# Using MVC3 ViewData inside Style attribute of div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html, razor, viewdata

I´m working on a MVC3 project.

I already have a decimal value into a ViewData["nReceived"] calculated in the controller. After that the controller calls to Index view.

I'm able to display it on Index view outside of a  element

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width: 42%;">Received  @ViewData["nReceived"]</div>
```

but I need to use this value as a property of  element replacing the width percentage.

I tried this with no success:

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width: @ViewData["nReceived"]%;">Received</div>
```

and also this:

```
@ViewContext.Writer
    .Write("<div class=\"bar bar-success\" style=\"width: @ViewData["nReceived"]%;">")
```

Any ideas on how to get it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work use `@()`

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width:@(ViewData["nReceived"])%;">Received</div>
```

Also Since you are using MVC3, you can try `ViewBag` as well

```
<div class="bar bar-success" style="width:@(ViewBag.nReceived)%;">Received</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. First option still not working. Using ViewBag i have the same problem that in origin. I can use it outside div element but not as a property

Comment: But both the way should work I tested this in my MVC3 as well as MVC4 apps.

Comment: What's the result you getting when trying this? and are you trying this in same view?

Comment: The result is that div element has no width, but if i use @(ViewBag.nReceived) or @(ViewData["nReceived"] outside the div element, the decimal value is displayed correctly, so i can be sure that it contains value

Comment: Sorry my mistake!!! I was trying to set a decimal value to the width property and this is not valid. Width property only allow entire values. Inserting a int32 value instead decimal into Viewbag or Viewdata works like a charm!! Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`style='width: @Html.Raw(ViewData["nReceived"])'` you're breaking your quotes and you need this to render out a little differently here

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not .ToRaw() in the @Html helper :(

Comment: you are correct it should be `Raw`, which version of MVC are you using?

Comment: I´m using MVC3 on Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Finally i was able to find Raw an d tried this <div class="bar bar-danger"style="width: @Html.Raw(System.Convert.ToString(ViewData["nReceived"]))%;"></div> since  Raw requires a string. No luck :(